# Why do my Google Sheet custom functions require this weird workaround?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mobile, custom-function

I’m creating custom functions in Google Sheets using their google apps script language. I’ve done my development on a laptop and it seems to work correctly.

However, when I open the sheet on my mobile device (iOS), the cell output for my custom functions get stuck at “Loading…” forever and never load. But I discovered this weird workaround, but I don’t know why it works or if there’s a better way: if I make a small, trivial change to one of the input cells, then close the sheet and reopen, the sheet will be correctly updated.

Note that if I just make a change to a cell, or add/delete a column etc, *without* closing and reopening, to force an update, it will still get stuck at “Loading…”.

Also note that if I close and reopen the sheet *without* making any change, it will still get stuck.

Any ideas of what’s going on here, and if there’s a better way to get my custom functions to correctly update without timing out?

I searched online for solutions, couldn’t find anything.

Update: Example sheet located at this link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12nm9EwuzqaN0jYUv75CquMhrcUGlVsmEPFoWd92yuWo/edit
Look at the “SeasonTest” tab, cell AS5. On a mobile device it always shows “Loading…” (unless the above workaround is used), but works fine on a desktop

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a minimal reproducible example, for example your custom function. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've also created a custom function in Sheets, which makes an HTTP call to retrieve the value, and it works well from both the web version and the mobile one. So I'd be interested in the code of your custom function

Comment: Google Apps Script code is executed in Google servers. Check if your mobile settings might somehow blocking / limiting the connection with the Google servers like a feature to save mobile data consumption. 
Try using a better Internet connection. If you need further help, please provide more details. 1) Custom function code, 2) describe the spreadsheet to have an idea of how complex it is and to know if that might affect the script performance 3) describe the type of Intenet connection that you are using.

Comment: Waxim Corp: I added a link to my spreadsheet so you can see if you can reproduce the issue yourself.      

ValLeNain: Can you provide example of your HTTP code? My function is reading in a table of data, doing a bunch of regular expressions, a few string splits, some minor math, then outputting a big 2D array (168 rows x  7 columns). The function is only called twice